# Able to construct a boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex inside a shared memory segment, but it is null when I try to access it

Tags: c++, boost, shared-memory

So, I create a segment of shared memory.  I create a boost::interprocess::vector in it, and and an interprocess_mutex.

The vector works fine.  I can get it, it's not null, I can use it.

When I try to get the mutex, it is null.

Here is the setup:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<int, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector;

managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
//I can construct a vector just fine
segment.construct<MyVector>("MyVector")(alloc_inst);
//constructing mutex returns without error, but when I try to access it as below, it is null
segment.construct<interprocess_mutex>("MyMutex")();
```

Later on, when I try to access it

```
  managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
  //The vector is there and not null
  MyVector *myvector = segment.find<MyVector>("MyVector").first;
  //The mutex is null when I try to access it.
  interprocess_mutex *mutex = segment.find<interprocess_mutex>("MyMutex").first;
  if (!mutex)
       //FAIL !!
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Should work in principle. Have you checked the return value of `segment.construct<>`?

Comment: @sehe ok, this is weird.  After I assign the return value of segment.construct and check it, it started working.   This makes no sense to me unless there is some lazy initialization magic happening.

Comment: perhaps `managed_shared_memory` went out of scope early?

Comment: Also, perhaps you have undefined behaviour elsewhere (e.g. do you synchronize the creation of the shared memory area?)